# reCaptcha v3 возвращсет ошибку

Tags: javascript, php, recaptcha

Установил google captcha на сайт но она работает както не правильно. Иногда проходит проверку, а иногда возвращает ошибку,
`{"success": false,"error-codes": ["missing-input-response"]}`

не понимаю почему так происходит. Просьба не кидаться помидорами, я только начинающий))

JS

```js
$("select").change(function () {
    if ($(this).val() == 'Заявка на желаемую дату доставки') {
        $('.calendar').show();
        $('.description_f').show();
    } else {
        $('.calendar').hide();
        $('.description_f').hide();
    }
});

$(function(){
    $(".tel").mask("+7(999)999-99-99");
    $.mask.definitions['h']='[A-Fa-f0-9]';
    $(".number_order").mask("hhhhhhh-hhh");
});

$(".sendMail").on("click", function () {

    //создаем экземпляр класс FormData, тут будем хранить всю информацию для отправки
    var formData = new FormData();

    //присоединяем  поля
    let name = $(".name").val().trim();
    let email = $(".email_home_form").val().trim();
    let tel = $(".tel").val().trim();
    let number_order = $(".number_order").val().trim();
    let type_appeal = $(".type_appeal").val();
    let checkbox_check = $(".checkbox_check").prop('checked');
    let calendar = $("#calendar").val();
    // ВОТ ТУТ ПРИНИМАЮ ТОКЕН ИЗ ФОРМЫ**************************************************************************
    let token = $("#token").val();
    // ВОТ ТУТ НЕ ДОКОНЦА ПОНИМАЮ ЧТО ПРОИСХОДИТ, ВЗЯЛ ИЗ ИНСТРУКЦИИ ПО КАПТЧЕ***********************************
    grecaptcha.ready(function() {
          grecaptcha.execute('6LeyrWUaAAAAAMxakIs0BmN9cQW6uRpk2fnW4_Il', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
              token = token;
              document.getElementById('token').value = token;
          });
        });
    // ***********************************************************************************************************


    if (name === '' || email === '' || tel === '' || number_order === '' || !checkbox_check ) {
        $('.modal_error').show();
        $.each($('.input-box input'), function (i, v) {
            if ($(this).val() == '' || !checkbox_check) {
                $(this).addClass('empty_field');
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass('empty_field');
            }
        });
        return false;
    }

    function isEmail(email) {
        var regex = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/;
        return regex.test(email);
    }

    if (!isEmail(email)) {
        $('.modal_error_email').show();
        return false;
    }

    formData.append('name', name);
    formData.append('email', email);
    formData.append('tel', tel);
    formData.append('number_order', number_order);
    formData.append('type_appeal', type_appeal);
    formData.append('calendar', calendar);
    // ВОТ ТУТ ДОБАВЛЯЕМ ТОКЕН В ОТПРАВКУ НА СЕРВЕР В ОБРАБОТЧИК
    formData.append('token', token);


    //отправляем через ajax
    $.ajax({
        url: "assets/ajax/mail_home.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        data: formData, //ОТПРАВЛЯЕМ ВСЕ ДАННЫЕ
        beforeSend: function () {
            $(".form_contact").prop("disable", true);
            $(".main-btn").attr("disabled", true);
            $(".loading_mail").show();

        },
        success: function (data) {
            $(".form_contact").trigger("reset");
            $(".loading_mail").hide();
            $('.input-box input').removeClass('empty_field');
            $(".main-btn").attr("disabled", false);
            $('.modal_success').show();
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

```html
HTML HTML HTML HTML
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=6LeyrWUaAAAAAMxakIs0BmN9cQW6uRpk2fnW4_Il"></script>
form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="contact-one__form form_contact">  <!---->
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="input-box has-feedback nameBlock">
                                                <label for="name" class="control-label ">Имя*</label>
                                                <input required type="text" placeholder="Иван Иванов" name="name" value="" class="name" >
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="input-box"> 
                                                <label for="email" class="control-label" >Email-адрес*</label>
                                                <input required type="email" placeholder="Email" name="email" value="" class="email_home_form">
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="input-box _req">
                                                <label for="tel" class="control-label">Номер телефона*</label>
                                                <input required type="tel" placeholder="+79997772255" name="tel" value="" class="tel">
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="input-box">
                                                <label for="number_order" class="control-label">№ Сделки*</label>
                                                <input required type="text" placeholder="0000000-я00" name="number_order" value="" class="number_order">
                                            </div>
                                        </div><!-- /.col-lg-6 -->
                                        <div class="col-lg-6">
                                            <div class="input-box">
                                               <label for="message" class="control-label">Тип обращения*</label>
                                                <select class="type_appeal" name="type_appeal">
                                                    <option value="Нет типа обращения">Тип обращения</option>
                                                    <option value="Заявка на доставку">Оформить доставку</option>
                                                    <option value="Заявка на желаемую дату доставки">Выбрать желаемую дату</option>
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-6 calendar">
                                            <div class="input-box">
                                                <label for="number_order" class="control-label">Дата*</label>
                                               <input type="date" class="calendar" id="calendar" name="calendar" placeholder="Дата" required>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 description_f">
                                            <p>Дата доставки назначается клиенту в соответствии с тарифной сеткой, оплаченной клиентом. 
                                            О дате доставки ЗАКАЗЧИК уведомляется дополнительно (за сутки до планируемой даты доставки). Подробнее читайте в <a class="description_p" href="javascript:void(0);">Процесс получения заказов</a>.</p> 
                                        </div>
                                        <br>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12">
                                            <div class="input-box"></div>
                                                <div class="checkbox">
                                                    <input checked id="checkbox_check" type="checkbox" name="agreement" class="checkbox__input checkbox_check">
                                                    <label for="checkbox_check" class="checkbox__label _error"><span>Я даю согласие на обработку персональных данных в соответствии с <a href="[[~15]]" target="_blank">Условиями</a>*</span></label>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-left">
                                            <br>
                                            <input type="hidden" id="token" name="token">
                                         <button class="main-btn sendMail">Отправить</button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

PHP PHP PHP PHP PHP

```
`<?php

$captcha;

if (isset($_POST['token'])) {
    $captcha = $_POST['token'];
}

$secretKey = 'тут СЕКРЕТНЫЙ КЛЮЧ';
// $ip = $_SERVER['REMOVE_ADDR'];

$url = 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret=' . $secretKey . '&response=' . $captcha;

$response = file_get_contents($url);
$responseKeys = json_decode($response, true);
header('Content-type: application/json');


if ($responseKeys["success"] && $responseKeys["score"] >= 0.1) {
    $mail_to = $_POST['email'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $tel = $_POST['tel'];
    $numb = $_POST['number_order'];
    $type_appeal = $_POST['type_appeal'];
    $calendar = $_POST['calendar'];
    $site_url = ((!empty($_SERVER['HTTPS'])) ? 'https' : 'http') . '://' .                 
$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    $mail_manager = 'mail@C.COM';
    if (mail($mail_manager, "Сообщение с сайта 'Стекловозов'",  " Тип обращения:     
$type_appeal \n Желаемая дата доставки: $calendar \n Имя: $name \n Телефон: $tel \n Почта: 
$mail_to \n Номер заказа: $numb \n ")) {
    $arResult['ok'] = "Y";
} else {
    $arResult['no'] = "N";
}
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
echo json_encode($response);
}

die();`
```

Comment: Какую ошибку-то?

Comment: `{"success": false,"error-codes": ["missing-input-response"]}` вот этот ответ.